# Calculate time difference between JSON format and PHP time

Tags: php, json, datetime

I obtain time from a JSON string as:

```
"2020-11-17T12:36:05.88481Z", for example.
```

Now I want to get the difference between the current time and this JSON time. I have looked at something like:

```
$start_date = new DateTime();
$since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime('2020-11-25 11:25:00'));//but need current time here
```

So I need the original Json format .e.g. ("2020-11-17T12:36:05.88481Z") to be converted first to:

`2020-11-17 12:36:05` // I think it will handle the decimal seconds.

Then (hopefully) I can put it into:

```
$start_date = new DateTime(); // current time
$since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime($converted_from_json));
```

I'm just wanting to look at elapsed time between the incoming JSON obtained time and the current time.

Comment: `$foo = new DateTime($that_date_string_from_the_json);`

Comment: this works: $foo = new DateTime("2020-11-23 09:03:28"); but not with decimals such as: $foo = new DateTime("2020-11-23T09:03:28.731550803Z"); Results in: " Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2020-11-23T09:03:28.731550803Z) at position..."

Comment: Sorry , should I have add the above to my original post, rather than as a comment?

Comment: Further comment: One less decimal place and it works: $foo = new DateTime("2020-11-23T09:03:28.73155080Z");// no error

Comment: The data you're giving as examples is varying wildly as far as the number of digits in the fractional seconds. Beyond 6 digits [microseconds] it's a tossup whether any system will accept it, and PHP certainly won't accept more than 8 digits. Unless you have a rock-solid use-case for requiring nanosecond precision _and_ a tightly-calibrated, high-precision clock, it's a waste of mental energy to specify/provide/deal with that level of precision.

Answer (score 0):

In the Json packet - I can also get time further down as:

```
"metadata": {
    "time": "2020-11-17T12:36:06.586022488Z",
    "frequency": 868.3,
    "modulation": "LORA",
    "data_rate": "SF12BW125",
    "coding_rate": "4/5",
    "gateways": [{
        "gtw_id": "eui-3133303734002e00",
        "timestamp": 2503673591,
        "time": "2020-11-17T12:36:05.88481Z",
        "channel": 1,
        "rssi": -114,
        "snr": -3.75,
        "rf_chain": 0
    }]
```

This has fewer decimals which seems to work.

Comment: Do not post answers to add information to your question, edit the original question.

Comment: sorry - will do

Comment: @Sammitch: I think you have misunderstood this contribution. It _is_ an answer, and not additional question material. The OP posted it into their question, and then edited the title to say it was [Solved]. I've undone that edit. Russell, if you wish, you can now click the tick mark to the left of this answer, to say it solved things for you. Self-answered questions are welcome here.